# How can I store an array of type char *array[3]?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm writing a basic shell and I parse my input into an a char *array[3], for example:

```
char *args[3] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
```

My intention is to store these array in another array and then pass them to execvp to pipe them.
Where I'm stumped is the following code:

```
char **commands[256];
commands[0] = args;
```

The previous lines of code throw an incompatible pointer type and I don't understand why, because I thought this was the proper syntax to store an array of type char *[]. I'm sure the solution is simple but it's alluding me.

EDIT:

Okay so the line of code

```
commands[0] = args;
```

Still throws an error. Also, when I attempt to pull a *command from **command using the following code:

```
char *temp;
temp = commands[0]
```

I get an incompatible pointer error. Shouldn't I be able to do this?

Comment: `commands[0] = args;` does not give an error, if your earlier code is exactly as you have written here.  However it probably doesn't do what you want.   (`char **commands[256]` is 256 instances of a `char **` and you're only using the first one of those to point to your `args` list - it's not clear what the other 255 are for)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want either:

```
char *commands[256];
```

or

```
char **commands;
```

What you have declared is an array of 256 pointers to pointers.

It's unclear from your example why you want to use another array, because your `args` array is already suitable for passing to `execvp`.

Comment: My intention is to use a for loop and pass multiple args to execvp but I need an array to store them in. For instance, commands[0] might be {ls, -l, NULL} and commands[1] might be {sort, NULL}. My intent is to also use this loop structure for piping. Does that help?

Comment: @user3476396 I hope you're allocating memory somewhere for all of these argument lists that you are going to make `commands[n]` point to